# Digital systems (differential equation for discrete values)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

I need to solve the following equation for the differences (differential equation for discrete values):

$$3y[n]-y[n-1]+y[n-2]={\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)}^{n}U[n]$$

I started by trying to find the homogeneous solution:

$$3-z^{-1}+z^{-2}=3-\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2}=3z^2-z+1$$

Homogeneous equation:

$$3z^2-z+1=0\leftrightarrow z=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4\times 3\times 1}}{2\times 3}\leftrightarrow z_1=\frac{1+\sqrt{11}i}{6};z_2=\frac{1-\sqrt{11}i}{6}$$

Since I gave complex numbers I don't know how to write the homogeneous solution with the constants $C_1$ and $C_2$. I also don't know how to find the particular solution.

$U[n]$ is Heaviside's function.

Comment: What is $U[n]$? This kind of equation is known as difference equation or linear recurrence equation.

Comment: @LutzL It's Heaviside's function. My problem is that I do not know what form the particular solution will have. How can I guess?

Answer (score 0):

Using $y[n]=0$ for $n<0$ you can multiply the equation with $z^n$ and sum over $n$ to get
$$
3Y(z)-zY(z)+z^2Y(z)=\frac1{1-\frac z2},\qquad Y(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty y[n]z^n
$$
so that 
$$
Y(z)=\frac1{(1-\frac z2)(3-z+z^2)}=\frac1{3(1-\frac12z)(1-q_1z)(1-q_2z)}
$$
where $q_1+q_2=q_1q_2=\frac13$ are the roots of the characteristic equation $3q^2-q+1=0$.
Computing the partial fraction decomposition and inserting the geometric series results in the explicit formula.